# MySQL IN Clause: table1.id IN table2.ids (comma separated list)

Tags: mysql, in-clause

table1

### id  | name | description

1   | name1 | descript1

2   | name2 | descript2

table2

### id  | term | ids

1   | term1 | 1,2,10

2   | term2 | 2,4,8

Something like:

SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE id IN 
  ( SELECT ids 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE term = 'term2'
  );

...but this only returns the first result.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON FIND_IN_SET(ids,table1.id) WHERE term = 'term2'`

Comment: Use a `JOIN`. Subselects in `IN()` are a real paininthea... for the engine.

Comment: thanks, that was close, this worked:

SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON FIND_IN_SET(table1.id,ids) WHERE table2.term = 'term2'

Comment: @huhuh Fix your database structure.  This will be a pain when your table grows.